# Spring boot : bean creation profile specific

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-profiles

I am working on a spring boot application.i am using spring boot version: 2.2.4-RELEASE

I am trying to create a bean specific for a profile.but the bean is not creating as expected.

Below is my configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class TestConfig {

  //below is the bean i need to be created for dev and test
  @Bean
  @Profile({“dev”, “test”})
  TestObject getTestObject() {

        //do something
  }

//below is the bean i need to be created for staging and prod
  @Bean
  @Profile({“staging”, “prod”})
  TestObject getTestObject() {

        //do something
  }


//someother beans common for all profiles

}
```

Service.java

```
@Service
public class Serviceclass {

  @Autowired
   private TestObject testObj;

   //some methods

}
```

I tried the above way, but the bean is
Not getting created for any of the profiles. Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be helpful.

**Update**: the application is failing to start as one of the service class has dependency on the bean i am trying to create.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean `bean is Not getting created for any of the profiles` ? can you show some output or error ?

Comment: @Deadpool application is failing to start as in one of the service has a dependency. Updating the question.

Comment: Where are you passing the active profile? can you add your YAML file and the command which you are using to run the application

Comment: @DeepakKumar from application logs i can see below: The following profiles are active: dev

Comment: @DeepakKumar how does application yml play a role here as i am trying to create a bean which doesnt take anything from properties file?

Comment: @JingJong I suspected that your profile configuration is not current and that is causing the issue while creating a bean

Comment: @DeepakKumar okay got it ..yeah but here i am not even using any properties

Answer (score 1):

In the note found in

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html

> Use distinct Java method names pointing to the same bean name

Answer (score 0):

You have to active profile for the application. You can pass runtime argument as as  **-Djava.profiles.active=dev**. It will solve your problem.
Also, need to create environment specific property files like **application-{env}.properties**

Comment: i already can see from logs that the active profile is : dev

Comment: Try to setter injection in TestObject instead of Field injection.. If any cyclic dependency present then you must have to use setter injection...

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the same method name. For some reason if i give the same name (method overloading) we are running into issues.  Found a similar thread which explains the same.

Thanks a lot everyone who tried to solve the issue.

Note: i will try to find the thread and will update the thread here which explains the same.